# i cant use google play service in android project

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play-services

i create project in eclipse and use Google map, but when run in YouWave(i instal Google play service) show white page that bottom page show Google without map! and say not connected;and when run in emulator say update your Google play services,need 6587000 but found 6171000,
thanks for your help

Comment: whats your minSdkVersion ??

Comment: minSdkVersion is 10 and targetSdkVersion is 21